# {Parse.com} Start Activity with motification msg data when push notification click from notification bar

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform, push-notification

I have successfully implemented the push notification tutorial for Android. Once the notification is received it will immediately perform an action based on the json objects passed via the BroadcastReceiver.

However we would like that the action only be performed once the user clicks the push notification alert in the notification tray. Is this possible? From the tutorials we can choose which activity is opened via the subscribe method.

I am trying to determine when a particular push notification is clicked to launch the app. I am sending the pushes with a custom action and receiving them fine. When the notification is clicked to open the app for the first time, I receive the action and push notification data in the extras. However, once the app is already open / backgrounded, the extras never change. If I open the app from a different push notification OR open the app just from the app icon, the extras remain the same as the original notification that opened the app (or no extras if the app was opened originally just by the icon).

This is my code in onResume() method of my activity

```
Intent intentNotification = getIntent(); 
        Bundle extras = intentNotification.getExtras(); 
        if (extras!=null) {
            String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );
            System.out.println("Message Data : "+jsonData);

        }
```

Any one please help me on this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this method into your Activity which is push notification open

```
@Override

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    setIntent(intent);
    if (extras!=null) {
        String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );
        System.out.println("New Notification Data : "+jsonData);

        String msg;

        try {
            JSONObject jMsg=new JSONObject(jsonData);

            if (jMsg.has("alert")) {
                msg=jMsg.getString("alert");
                Util.SaveToSharedPref(LoginActivity.this, Constant.ShaPreNotification, Constant.ShaPreNotfMessage, msg);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and onRecevie() method call one custom function which body is same as onNewIntent()

This is important because when app is completely closed i.e it is remove from recent apps /apps history at that time on receive method is called so it getting notification message.

and other time it call onNewIntent() method

Answer (score 0):

I also went through the same situation while using Xtify for push notification

I applied a simple logic of creating static variable according to the need. when the specific operation id completed . in my case user registers , then I would make the static variable to empty `(public static String MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE="")`. Unless the user doesn't register the variable contains the `value`

try to implement this logic ...
hope this can help to at least to start.

Comment: yes I m clearing notification message when opening app .but it not clearing from Bundle. that why it again and again display same message.

Comment: If this is ur problem , then don't create bundle object ... simple make global variable , assign value to it as per ur need and access it anywhere ..

Comment: I m not creating Bundle object . I m getting notification msg in onResume of activity.  Intent intentNotification = getIntent(); 
   Bundle extras = intentNotification.getExtras();

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
public static String MY_JSON_DATA;
Intent intentNotification = getIntent(); 
        Bundle extras = intentNotification.getExtras(); 
        if (extras!=null) {
            MY_JSON_DATA=extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );
            System.out.println("Message Data : "+MY_JSON_DATA);

        }
```

// when open the app , use the value from `MY_JSON_DATA` and after clear it like `MY_JSON_DATA=""`

Comment: I got solution thank God :) I m putting it in solution